# Unsure about calculating commission based on user input

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keybNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keybStr = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean yn = false;

    //Start of program
    System.out.println("Welcome to Currency Exchanger");
    System.out.print("Are you an Account Holder (y or n)?    ");
    String AccHolder = keybStr.next();
    boolean blnYN = true;

    //validation of y/n answer
    while (blnYN) {
        if (AccHolder.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            yn = true;
            blnYN = false;
            break;
        }//if 
        else if (AccHolder.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            yn = false;
            blnYN = false;
            break;
        }//else if 
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid value entered. Choose either y/n.");
            AccHolder = keybStr.next();
        }//else
    }//while

    //Start of menu choices
    System.out.println("Please choose from the following menu.");
    System.out.println("\n1: Exchange another currency for Sterling");
    System.out.println("2: Buy another currency from us");
    System.out.println("0: Exit");
    System.out.print("Which option?    ");
    int MenuChoice = keybNum.nextInt();


    //Exchange Variables (First option)
    double Euro = 1.37;
    double USAD = 1.81;
    double JapYen = 190.00;
    double Zloty = 5.88;

    //Buy Variables (Second Option)
    double EuroB = 1.21;
    double USADB = 1.61;
    double JapYenB = 163.00;
    double ZlotyB = 4.89;

    //First menu choice screen
    if (MenuChoice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Currencies to exchange into sterling?");
        System.out.println("Euro - EUR");
        System.out.println("USA Dollar - USD");
        System.out.println("Japanese Yen - JPY");
        System.out.println("Polish Zloty - PLN");
        System.out.print("Please enter the three letter currency:   ");

        //Currency input validation
        String CurChoice = "";
        boolean isCorrectCurrency = false;
        do {
            CurChoice = keybStr.next();
            isCorrectCurrency = CurChoice.matches("^EUR|USD|JPY|PLN$");

            if (isCorrectCurrency) {
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Invalid Currency Entered. Please Retry: ");
            }

        } while (!isCorrectCurrency);

        //Exchange amount calculator
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you wish to exchange of " + CurChoice + ": ");
        double ExcAmount = keybStr.nextInt();
        double result = 0.00;

        //Selection and calculation of user's input
        if (CurChoice.equals("EUR")) {
            result = ExcAmount / Euro;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else if (CurChoice.equals("USD")) {
            result = ExcAmount / USAD;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else if (CurChoice.equals("JPY")) {
            result = ExcAmount / JapYen;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else if (CurChoice.equals("PLN")) {
            result = ExcAmount / Zloty;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Right, this is where I am stuck. So this program is a currency exchange converter. The part I'm unsure about is to calculate the commission. At the start I ask the user if they're an account holder. If they're they don't get charged a commission, whereas if they're then they do. If the amount they wish to exchange is less than £1000 then they get charged a commission of 2%, and if its over £1000 then they get charged a commission of 1%. I wasn't sure how to implement this into my program, so i'm asking you guys to help.

Comment: Two remarks: (1) I think you better write a dedicated method for this and not interleave it with I/O; (2) I assume the 1% is on the money above `1'000` otherwise exchanging `1'000` would be cheaper than exchanging `999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after calculating the result:

```
double commission = 0.;
if (ExcAmount < 1000) {
    commission = result * 0.02;
} else {
    commission = result * 0.01;
}

result += commission;
String stringToPrint = "";
if (!yn) { //you could use meaningful variable names
    stringToPrint = "Commission = " + commission;
} else {
    stringToPrint = "Commission = Not charged";
}
System.out.println(stringToPrint + "\nTotal = " + (result - commission));
```

Comment: The answer is correct - based on the specifications - although in the financial world, most systems will charge 1% on the money **above** `1'000`. In other words, if one exchanges `£2'500`, one will charge `£35`: 2% on the first `£1'000` and 1% on the remaining `£1'500`.

Comment: you say commission not charged for account holder, So why should we add commission to result for account holder?

Comment: Its still not clear? Does that mean if user is not account holder then commission with be subtracted from the actual result that was currency converted else just add commission?

Comment: Where which line can you clarify? Can you paste output and tell exactly what is add and subtract logic there?

Comment: Enter the amount you wish to exchange of EUR: 500
500.0 in EUR =£364.96
Commission = 7.445255474452555
Total = 372.26277372262774                                                  That is my output there. as you can see the Total isn't the subtracted value

Comment: it's giving me right value `364.817518248175185` for total. I could see subtraction here in my above answer `System.out.println(stringToPrint + "\nTotal = " + (result - commission));`  do you have the same? If not please change.

Comment: I've got it going here now. Thanks for your help.